# Top keyword in Sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

`Select [Top n[PERCENT]]` from table_name.
in this Syntax what is the use of PERCENT keyword?

Comment: its a percent. in `TOP (expression) [PERCENT]` - expression is implicitly converted to a float value if PERCENT is specified; otherwise, it is converted to bigint.
That means if you write TOP 10 then will give 10 records and TOP 10 PERCENT then will give 10% records  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189463.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
TOP n [PERCENT]
```

n specifies how many rows are returned. If PERCENT is not specified, n is the number of rows to return. If PERCENT is specified, n is the percentage of the result set rows to return:

Try it on w3schools.com

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_top_percent&ss=-1

Answer (score 1):

Why not google it?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189463.aspx

So `SELECT TO 10 PERCENT` returns the top 10% of the rows from the select

Answer (score 1):

It returns the first n percent of rows matching your criteria.  Usually an ORDER BY clause is necessary to make the rows returned useful.

Comment: Should have been a comment IMHO

Comment: Yeah.  I have to agree with that.  Good call.

Answer (score 0):

1. It returns. top PERCENT% rows of select statement.
2. It is used as a hack to order in Views
   You can not order by in View, but if you add TOP 100 PERCENT it will be possible to order.